# C# Как ввести с клавиатуры в консоль число с буквой, чтобы между ними не было пробела?

Tags: c#

Ввожу строку командой:

```
string[] n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
//
int a = int.Parse(n[0]);
string b = (n[1]);
```

Но тогда между цифрой и буквой будет пробел, а нужно без него

Comment: Просто ввести без пробела и все.

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы хотите ввести число и строку без пробела, и разобрать результат на части, правильно? (Потому что иначе ваш код как раз ожидает пробел, и делит ввод на части по нему.)

В предположении, что это так, проще всего, наверное, вручную посчитать индексы:

```
var s = Console.ReadLine();
int idx = 0;
while (idx < s.Length && char.IsDigit(s[idx]))
    idx++;
if (idx == 0 || idx == s.Length)
    throw new FormatException();
var num = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, idx));
var text = s.Substring(idx);
```

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите ввести число и строку без пробела (как то так - `32hello`) то можно попробовать использовать регулярки:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d+)([^\d\s]+)");

string str = Console.ReadLine();
var m = reg.Match(str);

int i = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
string s = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

1. [Регулярные выражения в .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Элементы языка
   регулярных выражений — краткий справочник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите данные:");
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        string resultN = string.Empty;
        string resultS = string.Empty;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                resultN += c.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                resultS += c.ToString();
            }
        }

        int i = 0;
        Console.Write("\nЧисло: " + resultN + "\n" + "Символы: " + resultS + "\n\n");
        if (int.TryParse(resultN, out i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Парсинг числа: " + i.ToString());
            }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

P.S. Про `StringBuider` в курсе, да. Не стал усложнять.
И да, будет обрабатывать только ввод положительных целых чисел, но при необходимости проверку на ввод "-" легко добавить.

Comment: вводим "1a2b3c" ,  что будет на выходе? - "123" и "abc". Я не уверен что это нужный и ожидаемый результат. Стоит поправить предложенное решение. И практический совет - тестируйте то, что предлагаете если не уверены на 300% в правильности.